# Cannot prevent an ajax loaded form from submiting

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a web page where a user can load a form on the page by hitting a link on it. I use ajax for the loading procedure. All this is happening in a seperate main file.

The form load code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $(".evaluation").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var division = $("select#tmimata").prop("value");
        var action = $(".lesson select").prop("value");
        var table = $(".main-content table");
        if (table.length > 0 ){
            table.fadeOut();
        }
        $(".main-content").load('/evaluation/employee/'+employee_id+"/?division="+tmima+"&action="+action, function(){
            alert("successfully retrieved evaluation form");
        }).show();
    });
});
```

So it checkes if there is a previous loaded table in the main-content and then it removes it and loads the form in the same div with class "main-content". After this outside the click function I "catch" the submit event for the form

```
$(".evaluation_form").submit(function (event){
    console.log('inside form submit');
    var form = $(this);
    var tmima_id = $('select#divisions').prop('value');
    var action_id = (".action select").prop('value');
    data = form.serialize();
    //ajax call to post the data
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

(I have placed preventDefault() both at the top of submit and at the bottom as it is right now still the same)

The submit code is after the click function but inside the document.ready. But it won't work the form is submitted. I am betting it has to do that when the page loads(document.ready) it doesn't see the form (its not there it is loaded after a user clicks on a link) so it doesn't chatch the submit event on the form correct? Should I place the submit function inside the "load" callback function?

sample html code

```
<!---somewhere in the html file -->
<a href="#" class="evaluation">Evaluate employee</a>
<div class="main-content"></div>
```

and the form

```
<form class="evaluaton_form" action="" method="post">
    <!--form fields here -->
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save evaluation" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.evaluation_form', function(event) {
    console.log('inside form submit');
    var form = $(this);
    var tmima_id = $('select#divisions').prop('value');
    var action_id = (".action select").prop('value');
    data = form.serialize();
    //ajax call to post the data
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: where should this be placed?Anywhere insiden the $(document).ready()?

Comment: Lol, our answers were exactly the same!  You were first, I'm giving you the vote.

Comment: @Apostolos replace your submit() event function with this code

Comment: @Apostolos, this is a modification of the code you already have, just replace what you have with this.

Comment: You both are right, so I will give you both a vote!  Apostolos, you were exactly right with your theory about the handler not firing because the form was not present in the DOM.  The code that Praveen and RustyToms submitted uses an event delegate, which will attach the event to any DOM element matching the selector that is present in the DOM now OR in the future.

Comment: It won't work with or without the quotation marks (@RustyToms answer)

Comment: If it isn't working I think you need to post more code, the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Lol it works!!!! Thank you...I just had a syntax error!!!LOve this community here!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".evaluation_form", function (event){
    console.log('inside form submit');
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var tmima_id = $('select#divisions').prop('value');
    var action_id = (".action select").prop('value');
    data = form.serialize();
    //ajax call to post the data
});
```

It should work, the form wouldn't have to be on the page at page load.

Comment: should I use the "" on the document?

Comment: whoops, no, I don't think so.  I fixed it.